# Send data to server using socket.io with Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, express, socket.io

in simple form i use:

```
onsubmit="return sendMessage()" action="/register"
```

to send data with socket.io to server:

```
function sendMessage() {

    var name = document.getElementById("Name").value;

    socket.emit('new_rgs', {
        'name': name,
    });

    return false;
}
```

and i want to save result to text file too,
i use express.js to do this:

```
app.post('/register', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
    var info = {};
    info["name"] = req.body.Name;

    fs.appendFileSync("register.json", JSON.stringify(info));

    res.render('pages/register', {
        "send": 1
    });
});
```

but post method doesn't send anything :(
if you want check all codes [it's here](https://github.com/arsalanses/nodejs-beginning)

Comment: What is your form `enctype`?

Comment: i don't set this in form,it's important?

Comment: You're using urlencodedparser, so yes. It is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a separate call to the /register route. What your current code does is that it only does an emit to the socket. You need a separate AJAX call towards the register route.